# SwipeCard adapter trigger action when no more data

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, adapter, swipe

I am working on an application with a Tinder-like behaviour. One of the activities is a swipecard screen that I populate with JSON data from my server. The user is meant to see a card containing information about some other user, and he can swipe him right (to indicate meet) or left (to indicate ignore). I am using [this](https://github.com/Diolor/Swipecards) library to implement the swiping functionality and I fetch more data from the server in an AsyncTask as such:

```
// Get Cards from server
getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, savedInstanceState,
    new LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<ArrayList<CardVO>>() {
        @Override
        public Loader<ArrayList<CardVO>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
            return new PersonsLoader(IntrosActivity.this, LibraryAPI.getInstance().getCurrentUserId(), LibraryAPI.getInstance().getCurrentEvent().eventId);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<ArrayList<CardVO>> loader, ArrayList<CardVO> data) {
            thisAdapter.addData(data);
            mProgressDialog.hide();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaderReset(Loader<ArrayList<CardVO>> loader) {
            mProgressDialog.hide();
        }
    }
).forceLoad();
```

`thisAdapter` is an ArrayAdapter associated with the swipe library and it holds the data that comes from the server. Currently I ask for more data from the server when I have less than 3 cards in my adapter.

Part of the intended functionality is (just like in Tinder), when a user indicates to meet another user, I check to see whether this is a double match, and if so, I display a dialog message saying they were matched together and they can now start messaging each other.

The problem I am facing is the following: When the user exhausts the list of cards (they have swiped through every relevant card so far), I want to redirect them to a static screen. I am unsure what the trigger for this action should be.

I tried the obvious choice and redirected them when `thisAdapter` becomes empty. This resulted in a bug that I can't seem to find a solution too: if I swipe right to meet the last person in the adapter (and they also want to meet me), the dialog shows briefly and then the activity to redirect is triggered, taking me straight to the static screen.

Any suggestions on how I can get around this? Or refactor the code to something more robust? I am essentially looking for a clever way to trigger the `NoMoreMatchesActivity` that takes the user to the static screen.